Request.getCurrent().getRequestId() returns the same id if called inside a queueable chain
So if a have a chain of queueables that send outbound messages I grab the requestId using Request.getCurrent().getRequestId() and send it with the request for uniqueness it returns the same request ID on each queueable even though it's a sepereate context is this as expected if so is there another generic way I can get a non repeating ID that isn't unique to queueables (no queueable job id).

Do you need to be able to track the ID back to some specific processing through Salesforce logs?

How about using a random UUID?

It was shot down but yeah that was the other but ideally what we want is a “guaranteed” unique ID I know the odds of getting the same uuid you have likely better odds of being struck by lightning 55 times and surviving but that’s been the main sticking point on all of these

I like the use of the recently introduced UUID class as per PhilW; you could also use an auto-number field on a database object as that will also be unique - though requiring an insert + query per queuable
